# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS: can't install package libXtst6:i386

Tags: 16.04, package-management, software-installation

I am trying to install Wind River software development system. It doesn't explicitly support 16.04 but for 14.04 it requires:

> ```
> # Ubuntu 14.04 - 64 bit
> # Mandatory for running the installer
> sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libXtst6:i386
> # Optional packages for removing command-line warnings
> sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 unity-gtk2-module:i386
> ```

This works fine on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libXtst6:i386
```

but on 16.04 LTS I get:

```
E: Unable to locate package libXtst6:i386
```

(the first two packages install ok).

How can I install `libXtst6:i386`?

Comment: Wich software requires you to install those packages? Where does it say you need those packages, or what instructions are you following?

Comment: It's a Wind River software development system. It doesn't explicitly support 16.04 but for 14.04 it requires:  ubuntu 14.04 - 64 bit
 # Mandatory for running the installer
 sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libXtst6:i386
 # Optional packages for removing command-line warnings
 sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 unity-gtk2-module:i386

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no package with capital letter in its name. This is a standard policy for Debian packages.

- `libXtst6:i386` wrong name
- `libxtst6:i386` correct name

See [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libXtst6&searchon=names&suite=xenial&section=all)

Answer (score 0):

Since it works on Ubuntu 14.04 and not 16.04, that means it's a Trusty package and not a Xenial package. Try downloading this package from [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/i386/libxtst6/2:1.2.2-1).

Comment: If my answer solves your problem please mark it as the solution to benefit the community :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it did fix my problem but the answer below addresses the main problem I think, i.e. the package was mispelled.

Answer (score 0):

Execute following commands to be able to install i386 versions of libraries:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```